# How to decide boundary for the foreground region for the fingreprint image

Tags: java, image, algorithm, image-processing, fingerprint

I am writing one application for image processing in java for the fingerprint image. In this I have completed with image binarization,image thinning and also done with the minutiae extraction.But to get the true minutiae from the image i have to do post-processing for the fingerprint image.

I want to remove the border minutiae from the extracted minutiae.I have studied various research papers for the post-processing on fingerprint image.After all these i come to know that i have to fix the foreground area for the fingerprint image to remove border minutiae.

Can any one please tell me how to  decide boundary for the foreground region for the fingreprint image ?
Or any method to remove border minutiae from the fingerprint image.

**Input Image**
[image]

**Output Image**
[image]

Comment: Could you provide some sample image? Insert images or links in your post with the input image and the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered elswhere: do a search on the words image, segmentation finger. There are dozens of paper on the subject. 
Here is a technique that works quite well, though:
divide your image into 15x15 blocks (there are two edges in which the blocks might not be quite 15x15 if the image width or height is not divisible by 15), then calculate the mean intensity (grey level) and then [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) of intensity on the block. Then exclude from your final image any block whose variance is less than a threshold value. Experiment with various thresholds to find the one you find best suits you.